# Zipping up a folder without extra folders in the zipped file

Tags: php, zip

So, I understand it's pretty easy to zip a folder and its contents given that php.net and stackoverflow are full of sample codes. I am trying to zip up a folder as well. This is my code:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open('myzip.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach (glob("/Volumes/Data/Users/username/Desktop/Archive/some/thisFolder/*") as $file) {
    $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();
```

My script is running in a folder, say on Desktop, and I want to zip `thisFolder` and its contents. The above code WORKS. But, the problem is that when I unzip the `myzip.zip` created, I get a structure like

```
Volumes>Data>Users>username>Desktop>Archive>some>thisFolder
```

and then I find the contents inside the 8th folder (`thisFolder`) in this case. How can I change this code so that when I unzip `myzip.zip`,I would straightaway see the folder `thisFolder` with the contents inside it instead of having to navigate through folders 7 times before getting my content?

I tried to change the path and silly things like that. But, it doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Use argument 2 for addFile()

Answer (score 1):

```
bool ZipArchive::addFile ( string $filename [, string $localname ] )
```

filename
The path to the file to add.

localname
local name inside ZIP archive.

You can use the `pathinfo` function to each $file in your loop, in order to retrieve the filename without the path, and then, use it as second parameter to the addFile method.

pathinfo doc [here](http://php.net/pathinfo)

Here is an example that could solve your problem:

```
// Create your zip archive
$zip = new ZipArchive;

// open it in creation mode
$zip->open('myzip.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);

// Loop on all your file
$mask = "/Volumes/Data/Users/username/Desktop/Archive/some/thisFolder";
$allAvailableFiles = glob($mask . "/*")
foreach ($allAvailableFiles as $file)
{
    // Retrieve pathinfo
    $info = pathinfo($file);

    // Generate the internal directory
    $internalDir = str_replace($mask, "", $info['dirname']);

    // Add the file with internal directory
    $zip->addFile($file, $internalDir . "/" . $info['basename']);
}

$zip->close();
```

Comment: This is somewhat close to what I am looking to do. The only problem now is that there's a sub-folder inside `thisFolder` and that is being converted to a file as well. Instead of a 'myzip' folder with the files and then the subfolder inside it! What do I change further?

Comment: Then you have to use again the result from `pathinfo` to isolate you directory

Comment: Added an example that should do what you need (not tested)

Comment: Doesn't work. But, I'm going the other way now. Copying the folder to my current directory and then zipping it the regular way. Thanks a lot for the help though. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want everything in the file to be a name relative to your starting folder, use `chdir()` to start from there:

```
chdir("/Volumes/Data/Users/username/Desktop/Archive/some/thisFolder");
foreach (glob("*") as $file) {
    $zip->addFile($file);
}
```

Actually, I don't think this will work when `$file` is a subdirectory -- `addFile` doesn't recurse automatically. There's a comment in the documentation that shows how to write a recursive zip function:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addemptydir.php

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. So, I'm using another logic to do this. :)